# Draw figures using k-nn with different values of k

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

I want to plot figures with different value of k for k-nn classifier.
My problem is that the figures seem to have same values of k.
What I have tried so far, is to change the value of k in each run in the loop:

`clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=counter+1)` 
But all the figures seem to be for `k=1`

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
data = fetch_california_housing()
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

c = np.array([1 if y > np.median(data['target']) else 0 for y in data['target']])
X_train, X_test, c_train, c_test = train_test_split(data['data'], c, random_state=0)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import mglearn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(20, 6))
for counter in range(3):      
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=counter+1) 
    clf.fit(X_test, c_test)
    plt.tight_layout()  # this will help create proper spacing between the plots.
    mglearn.discrete_scatter(X_test[:,0], X_test[:,1], c_test, ax=ax[counter])
    plt.legend(["Class 0", "Class 1"], loc=4)
    plt.xlabel("First feature")
    plt.ylabel("Second feature")
    #plt.figure()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why all the plots look the same is that you are simply plotting the test set every time instead of plotting the model predictions on the test set. You probably meant to do the following for each value of `k`:

- Fit the model to the training set, in which case you should replace `clf.fit(X_test, c_test)` with `clf.fit(X_train, c_train)`.
- Generate the model predictions on the test set, in which case you should add `c_pred = clf.predict(X_test)`.
- Plot the model predictions on the test set, in which case you should replace `c_test` with `c_pred` in the scatter plot, i.e. use `mglearn.discrete_scatter(X_test[:, 0], X_test[:, 1], c_pred, ax=ax[counter])` instead of `mglearn.discrete_scatter(X_test[:, 0], X_test[:, 1], c_test, ax=ax[counter])`.

Updated code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import numpy as np
import mglearn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = fetch_california_housing()

c = np.array([1 if y > np.median(data['target']) else 0 for y in data['target']])

X_train, X_test, c_train, c_test = train_test_split(data['data'], c, random_state=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(20, 6))

for counter in range(3):

    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=counter+1)

    # fit the model to the training set
    clf.fit(X_train, c_train)

    # extract the model predictions on the test set
    c_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

    # plot the model predictions
    plt.tight_layout()
    mglearn.discrete_scatter(X_test[:,0], X_test[:,1], c_pred, ax=ax[counter])
    plt.legend(["Class 0", "Class 1"], loc=4)
    plt.xlabel("First feature")
    plt.ylabel("Second feature")
```